# This window doesn't close properly - how should I try to fix it?

Tags: windows

I'm getting a proper draft from this window not forming a proper seal.  Is there some fairly easy DIY I can try, or do I need to get a professional in?

I don't need to open this window during the winter, so if there was some artificial seal I could fit that might work.

[image: my window]

Comment: The nicest looking for a fast fix till next spring, would be a window draft stop film.  Comes with double sided tape and transparent plastic film.  Go around outside of window frame with tape and stick film on, then run hair dryer over it to tighten/smooth film.

Comment: @crip659 That is the worst product I've ever had the displeasure of using. The tape usually fails and doesn't remove easily from the trim. If your trim is painted then say goodbye to some paint. I would recommend taping it with blue painter's tape because it will actually hold and peel easily in the spring.

Comment: _Where_ has the seal failed? Is it somewhere between the sash and glass? Between the sash and frame? Is one of the latches not pulling tight? Is it between the frame and wall? You should be able to identify by feel where the breeze is blowing through and get us a couple of close-up shots of that area to help us identify the best way of fixing it.

Comment: Basically the window isn't closing properly - it's between the sash and the frame, if I have the lingo correct.  I'd say the latches are not pulling it tight enough.

Comment: Clear, focused, close up pictures of the two latches from several angles (and, possibly with the window open, if it's not too frigid) would be helpful. Someone might spot an issue with one or both latches. A good first thing to check would be to ensure that all the screws for the latch hardware are tight, but not so tight that you're stripping the holes.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus   I have had decent luck with it, but it was years ago and they might have change the tape since.  It did do the job of stopping drafts though the winters.

Comment: You can't put 'shrink wrap' on that window, the handles are in the way.

Answer (score 2):

Given the type of window, I suspect you need to replace the worn out seal with something that has a profile like [this one](https://www.screwfix.com/p/stormguard-upvc-door-window-seal-black-20m/89084) and sold specially for UPVC doors and windows. It should push right into the grooves around the window itself once you remove the existing (and presumably worn out) seal. If my guess is correct, it should seal more effectively than the adhesive brush seals suggested in another answer.

The seals I've seen that have needed replacing haven't perished but they've been permanently squashed out of shape and sometimes have holes worn or cut into them where the frame has rubbed (or feet if it's at the bottom of a door).

[image: Profile of UPVC window seal]

Answer (score 1):

You could get a new handle for the top one, to match the bottom one… then you could shim the latch plates.

You might be able to shim the top handle, but it looks like it latches 'inside' the frame. The bottom one goes outside, so will be a lot easier to deal with.

Empty soft drinks cans make great shims. Cut two or three rectangular sections. Use a small file [even a nail file will do] to smooth out the edges so they're not sharp & possibly slim one end to give the latch an easier ride as it first meets the shim. Alternatively, lap the shims round the corner, so the latch rides over more easily. Get some good contact adhesive [Evo-Stik etc] & follow the instructions on the tube.

As they famously say on Blue Peter… here's one I prepared earlier.
This is from a fridge door light, but the principal is the same.

[image]

The handles will now close tighter.

BTW, I'm assuming, as those look like generic 'Euro handles', I wouldn't expect to find 'brush strip'. There should be rubber/silicone seal. It's replaceable, but it shouldn't perish or weaken in at least 20 years, so you have to tighten against it more, rather than replace it.

As mentioned elsewhere, you need to be sure that condensation isn't between the panes, otherwise its time for a new unit, as the gas seal has gone. This won't in itself contribute to a draught, but it will lessen the overall heat retention of the pane. btw, you don't need to replace the entire unit to fix the glass itself - those panes snap out & back in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the condition of the brush weather stripping and consider replacing it.

[image]

You haven't explicitly stated where the draft is penetrating so this is just my best guess.

---

Is this condensation in between the panes of glass? The argon seal might be broken. There is no DIY remedy for this.

[image]

Comment: Well, the draft is coming most clearly from the actual sides of the window, but I suspect there is a problem between the panes as well, as you say.  I think I'll need to get it replaced.

Comment: FYI- the OP has just clarified in a comment that the issue seems to be between the sash and frame and he suspects the latches aren't closing properly. Of course, new weather stripping might fix the problem if the old weather stripping is worn, and the old weather strip may have moved causing the latch to no longer be able to close completely.

Comment: Top of the window does seem to be out more than the bottom.  Might need more than a simple replace of the weather stripping.

Comment: @FreeMan I do not enjoy pulling teeth via comments with an unresponsive poster. If they couldn't be bothered to engage promptly in this community then I'd prefer to see their question deleted to be honest.

Comment: Hrm... it's been 2 hours since the question was posted. The OP commented on your answer within one hour (they both say "2 hours ago"), and responded to my comment within probably 15 minutes. Not sure how much more responsive you could ask for, especially considering some requests for more info go ignored for _years_.

Comment: Also, good catch on the possibility of condensation between the panes - I just noticed that comment.

Comment: I'll upload a photo of the handles when I get home from work.  But I do think they're probably bad enough that replacing them is the least I can do, and if there's a problem with the actual panes I might just have the whole thing replaced.